# Compare swapped two list of each value using linq in c#

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my cases,

```
ListA "1", "2", "3"
ListB "2", "1", "3"
```

**If ListA == ListB, => it should return true since ListA values are in ListB**.

```
ListA "1", "2", "3"
ListB "1", "2", "3", "4"
```

=> **it should return false since ListB of 4 is not in ListA.**

Can anybody help on this?

Comment: Try to use HashSet instead of Lists

Comment: What should happen if LISTA "1", "2", "3" and LISTB "2", "1", "3", "3"? Or are you worried about that case?

Comment: I think you're right @Sinatr. The solution I came up with is already on there using sequenceequal and orderby.

Comment: @KSib Actually it is invalid case since having duplicate values. Anyway it should return false since ListA and LisB length is not equal.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think your answer is in the link @Sinatr likely posted

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `Except` and then `Any`

```
var result = !ListB.Except(ListA).Any();
```

Comment: This will work assuming no duplicate values ever show up in ListB.

Comment: @Ksib: Duplicate will also work fine. Say `ListB` has an extra 3, still result returns `true`.

Comment: It wasn't a question for you, I was clarifying for cgsabari that this is fine if he doesn't mind duplicates. If he does mind duplicates then this won't work. Actually, it looks like this won't work for his requirements as he commented just now

Answer (score 2):

If lists contain only unique values you can use `HashSet` and [`SetEquals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516(v=vs.110).aspx) method

`new HashSet(listA).SetEquals(new HashSet(listB));`